SymPy in Fabric
Anyone facing issues to use/install SymPy in the Fabric environment of Synapse?
Tried to install but couldn't use Sympy within Fabric. I'm working on this python code to include some algebraic expressions but Sympy doesn't seem to work, not sure if it has to do with Fabric.

Are you trying to install and work with sempy in your synapse environment or the fabric notebooks itself?

In the fabric notebook itself. is there some settings to consider?
